# Convergence Proof How to

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, proof-writing

Any suggestions on how to set up the following proof?

If $X_n$ -> -∞, then 1/Xn -> ∞ as n-> ∞.

I know the statement is true, and in the proof, I should use the definition of convergence. I'm just not sure how to set it up.

Comment: Do you need to use epsilon-delta? Or do you have order rule and sandwich rule? What is the level of rigour expected?

Comment: I don't need to use epsilon delta, but that is what I know best. I am familiar with the Squeeze Thm too.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**: If $X_{n}\rightarrow X$, then for all $n$ sufficiently large,
$|X_{n}-X|<1$ and hence
$$
\left|\, \frac{X_{n}}{n} - 0 \, \right|=\frac{\left|X_{n}\right|}{n}=\frac{\left|X_{n}-X+X\right|}{n}\leq\frac{\left|X_{n}-X\right|+\left|X\right|}{n}<\frac{1+\left|X\right|}{n}.
$$
What can you conclude?

Comment: That (1+|X|)/n < ε? So, by definition Xn/n converges?

Comment: Yes. Though you should probably say something like, "for each $\epsilon > 0$ and $n$ sufficiently large, $\frac{1 + |X|}{n} < \epsilon$". Or alternatively, you can just say $\frac{1 + |X|}{n} \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: Ok, thanks that helps a lot!